# Expo Barcode scanner returns a different value for same barcode

Tags: react-native, expo, barcode, barcode-scanner

i am using expo barcode scanner to scan some barcode, when I scan the data value returned is different every time. I thought the barcode is supposed to have one unique number that does not change or am I wrong? here is my implementation

```
const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    try {
      console.log(type);     //this returns 1024
      console.log(data);     //this value is different every time
      setData(data);
      setScanned(true);
      alert(`Bar code with type ${type} and data ${data} has been scanned!`);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(`we did not recognize the barcode.Please try again`);
      console.error("Unable to parse string: ", error);
    }
  };

<BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        barCodeTypes={[BarCodeScanner.Constants.BarCodeType.code93]}
        style={[StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, styles.minicontainer]}
      />
      {scanned && <Button title={"Tap to Scan Again"} onPress={Rescan} />}
    </View>
```

on the `console.log(data)` a different value is returned should it be this way? or is there something wrong somewhere.

ps: I do not have the barcode with me it was sent to me and , i am scanning them through my computer screen.Can this be the sure?